# Autocomplete AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tengo lo siguiente:

index.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filter" ng-change=""/>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.loadFilter= function(cadena) {
    AppService.loadFilter(cadena) => esto ya me devuelve el filtrado
}
```

Necesito que cuando escriba 2 letras, llame a un servicio rest que me devolvera un lista ya filtrada

Comment: y cual es el error?

Comment: Que has intentando, la función **loadFilter** donde la llamas? agrega mas contenido...